# Is the 39 melachot concept halacha l’moshe misinai

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, maseches-shabbos, oral-torah, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

Are the 39 categories melacha prohibited on Shabbat Halacha lemoshe misinai, or drash from the rabbis (deriving it from the juxtaposition of the Shabbat commandment to the mishkan)?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.73b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.49b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en